# Same Path for two resources in jersey

Tags: java, spring, jersey

Is it possible to map same path for two resources ?

Ex: Resource1.java

```
@Path("/users")
```

Ex : Resource2.java

```
@Path("/users")
```

Is this possible ?  Both the classes have different sub paths still it fails and give me 500 internal server error with servlet init error.

Answer (score 7):

The request matching rules specified in section 3.7.2 of the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jaxrs-1.0-final-spec.pdf) basically presume that each resource class will have an unambiguous, unique `@Path` expression associated with it.

To be honest, if you find yourself needing to specify the same path for two different resources then you should probably merge the resources.

Answer (score 4):

I think you actually can have the same path if you change something else about the request.

If I change the `@produces` and `@consumes` on each method I can, for instance, return XML for one of the methods and JSON for the other.

```
@produces(Application.XML)
@Path("/path")
public void methodA();

@produces(Application.jSON)
@Path("/path")
public void methodB();
```

Answer (score 4):

If the paths have different subpaths then you shoud specify the paths more fully in the separate `@Path` attributes, for example:

`@Path("/users/{id:[a-z0-9]+}/sub1/")`

`@Path("/users/{id:[a-z0-9]+}/sub2/")`

If you cannot specify them to the extent that it is clear which resource to call given any specific path then Jersey won't be able to decide which resource to call.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using one class mapped to jersey and have 2 helper classes that you delegate to to keep your code clean.

Answer (score 1):

Jersey will give you an error if you make a request where multiple resources might be able to respond. That is, the resources have ambiguous paths. However, I don't think that's the error you're getting here, if the overall path is not-ambiguous as you say.